# Apache Drill support for all ANSI SQL 2003 queries

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, apache-drill

As puublished in Apache Drill documentation, it supports full ANSI SQL 2003. My question here is how exactly Drill can execute queries in which row level data updated or deleted on HDFS/HIVE ? AS we all know its not possible to modify data in HDFS. 
1 more request, can anyone please create a tag for 'Apache Drill' as it requires high credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Drill supports more than just HDFS filesystems. S3, local Linux filesystem, NTFS, MapR-FS in addition to HDFS.

Currently Drill doesn't allow for single record updates, but I think that functionality is on the roadmap.